# Read multiple lines from a text file then iterate a function by inserting the read file on to it

Tags: javascript

I had a program that reads a specific line from a text file then logs the line and It works fine. What I was trying to add to it was the functionality to read multiple lines from the text file then insert the read lines to a different function that processes a result of the specific lines that are read then append them to a new file that was created.
My question is 1. How can I make my current `get_line` function read and return multiple lines, it currently only can read 1 line then log it. 2. How can I make my `insertLine` function iterate so that every time it completes running it will call the function again but `line2` as a parameter until it gets to `line20` then stops to iterate. Is it possible? The code below will explain it better I commented the questions in the code.

```js
function get_line(file, line_no, cb) {
  var stream = fs.createReadStream(file, {
    flags: 'r',
    encoding: 'utf-8',
    fd: null,
    mode: '0666',
    bufferSize: 64 * 1024
  });

  var fileData = '';
  stream.on('data', function(data) {
    fileData += data;

    var lines = fileData.split('\n');

    if (lines.length >= +line_no) {
      stream.destroy();
      cb(null, lines[+line_no]);
    } else
      fileData = Array(lines.length).join('\n');

  });

  stream.on('error', function() {
    cb('Error', null);
  });

  stream.on('end', function() {
    cb('File end reached without finding line', null);
  });
};

//Question 1: 
//x is equal to line 1 to 20, currently only can read 1 line 

get_line('filePath', x, function(err, line) {
  //expected
  console.log('line1: ' + line1);
  console.log('line2: ' + line2)
  console.log('line3: ' + line3)
  //ETC...
})
//Question 2:
//do I need to write 20 insertLine functions to append the result of line1,  //line2,line3...line20 or can I some how iterate them to add 1 to line //eachtime the function runs until it gets to 20 then stop running function
insertLine(line1, function(err, result) {
  fs.appendFileSync('newFilePath', result)
})

//next time the function runs it runs as line2 etc...
insertLine(line2, function(err, result) {
  fs.appendFileSync('newFilePath', result)
})
//until line20
```

Comment: Clarifying here— will it read lines 1-20, then 2-21, 3-22, and so on, or 1-20, 2-20, 3-20, until it only reads line 20? It would also help to have a link to the actual text file you are using so we can test and produce the actual output you're looking for.

Comment: It will read the specific line 1,2,3,4...,20 then stops at 20(includes 20). When it reads it only reads 1 line at a time, not 2-20 or so. Does that explain it well. @BrandonMcConnell

Comment: the text file can be any file with multiple lines of text (at least 20 lines). @BrandonMcConnell

Comment: My only other question is you mentioned a "result of the specific lines". What function are you wanting to pass the lines into? Are you just developing a script that will iterate and print out each line of a function. I want to make sure that I am preparing what you are looking for here.

Comment: no, the function takes in the data(i.e. line1,2..) then processes a result in which the function crunched then that result will be appended to the newly created text file. The function is basically the same format as I added above but I can add the one I'm using if that necessary. @BrandonMcConnell

Comment: I've studied your `on('data'...` line above and it's still not clear to me what this should be doing. Could you please add an example of a few lines that would get passed in and what should actually be done to them (in processing) that generates the correct return value?

Comment: by "example of a few lines that would get passed" you mean the parameters to get passed in when calling the ```get_line``` function?@BrandonMcConnell

Comment: as regards to your ```on('data'...``` question,  data is a buffer that needs to convert to a string.@BrandonMcConnell